# SQL query with multiple parameters in where

Tags: php, sql, where-clause

I have a simple database like this :

```
Name     id
-----------
music    1
sport    2
theatre  3
```

I just want to display

> music
>
> theatre

I call a function with the ids and want to show name corresponding, my query looks like this, but nothing happen

```
$array = array(1,3);
$id = implode(',', $array);
    
$result = doQuery("SELECT Name
                    FROM categories c
                    WHERE c.id IN '" . $id. "'
                    ");
                    
    if(hasRows($result)){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
            echo $row[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: After making a DB call, it's often a good idea to [check for errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). Also, you should note that you're learning a deprecated library -- consider switching to the newer `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: `in` requires `()` to be valid syntax, but depending on your flavor of sql (you didn't specify rdbms) you might need to either use a dynamic sql query, or split your delimited array into a table for `in (select id from table)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using IN, you must place the conditions in parenthesis but in you case you are not using them so try something like this:

```
$array = array(1,3);
$id = implode(',', $array);

$result = doQuery("SELECT Name
                FROM categories c
                WHERE c.id IN (" . $id. ")
                ");

if(hasRows($result)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        echo $row[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need your IN wrapped in ( ) not ' '.

```
$result = doQuery("SELECT Name
                   FROM categories c
                   WHERE c.id IN (" . $id. ")
                    ");
```